# I'm trying to get the same result from a Union and a Join for Babe Ruth's Career WAR

Tags: sql, join, statistics, aggregate-functions

I have two tables of baseball data. One has batter WAR and the other pitching WAR. I can get the result I'm looking for (in this case Babe Ruth's pitching and batting WAR) in the Union statement but not the Join statement.

```
SELECT b.[name_common],SUM(b.[WAR]) AS WAR
FROM [MLB].[dbo].[war_daily_bat] b
WHERE b.playerID = 'ruthba01'
GROUP BY b.[name_common],b.[playerID]

UNION

(      
SELECT p.[name_common],SUM(p.[WAR]) AS WAR_PITCH
FROM [MLB].[dbo].[war_daily_pitch] p
WHERE p.player_ID = 'ruthba01'
GROUP BY p.[name_common],p.[player_ID]
    )
```

But I cannot get the Join to give me the same result, this only gives me Ruth's batting WAR in years he was a pitcher. If I take out the team_ID OR year_ID part of the WHERE clause, the result is multiples too high.

```
SELECT MAX(B_NAME), SUM(B_WAR), SUM([P_WAR])
    FROM 
    (SELECT 
        MAX(b.name_common) AS B_NAME
        ,SUM(b.[WAR]) AS B_WAR
        ,SUM(p.[WAR]) AS P_WAR
        
    FROM [MLB].[dbo].[war_daily_bat] b
        FULL OUTER JOIN [MLB].[dbo].[war_daily_pitch] p ON b.playerID = p.player_ID
    WHERE b.playerID = 'ruthba01' 
        AND p.team_ID = b.team_ID AND p.year_ID = b.year_ID
    
    GROUP BY b.name_common
        ) t
```

If anyone has any thoughts on how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: your where clause in your second query (the join one) is most likely the issue.  `AND p.team_ID = b.team_ID AND p.year_ID = b.year_ID` should be part of your ON clause.

Comment: This comment helped me rethink what I was trying to do. I came up with this and it works!!

'''SELECT  MAX(a.name_common) AS NAME, SUM(WAR_B) AS WAR_B, SUM(WAR_PITCH) AS WAR_P FROM

(SELECT b.name_common,SUM(b.WAR) AS WAR_B
FROM [MLB].[dbo].[war_daily_bat] b
WHERE b.playerID = 'ruthba01'
GROUP BY b.[name_common],b.[playerID]) a

FULL OUTER JOIN

(SELECT p.name_common,SUM(p.WAR) AS WAR_PITCH
FROM [MLB].[dbo].[war_daily_pitch] p
WHERE p.player_ID = 'ruthba01'
GROUP BY p.[name_common],p.[player_ID]) b

ON a.name_common = b.name_common;'''